# document.getElementById causes jquery document ready to be executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

This code is supposed to run over to load.php and get some data in xml format, parse it, and load it in a div and display it. It works great, except the data from load.php is displayed twice. Is there another way to do this that won't cause the data to be shown twice? I've seen a number of posts related to the document ready function causing this problem, but can't seem to figure out how to apply any solutions to this case. I am putting this in the head tags on my page. I really want to keep this format, because eventually I'll POST some data to the load.php page.

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'load.php',
        success: loadReturn
    });

    function loadReturn(data) {
        var xml = $.parseXML(data);
        $xml = $(xml);

        $errorcode = $xml.find('errorcode');
        $data = $xml.find('data');

        document.getElementById("defaultcode").innerHTML = $data.text();
        $("#defaultcode").fadeIn(300);
    }
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="defaultcode" style><h3>a title</h3><p>blah blah</p><h3>a title</h3><p>blah blah</p></div>
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById("defaultcode")` on one line and `$("#defaultcode")` on the next?

Comment: I'm surprised at the result, given that there's only one "defaultCode" element, and innerHTML should replace anything that's already in there - even if loadReturn were called twice (which it shouldn't be), data.text() should only be there once. Can you paste in the HTML of defaultcode, as your browsers' Inspector shows it after initialization? (right-click the text, click Inspect Element)

Comment: I'm a noob. better way to do it?

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? Is this code came from an ajax response?

Comment: sure thing: <div id="defaultcode" style><h3>a title</h3><p>blah blah</p><h3>a title</h3><p>blah blah</p></div>

Comment: `success: loadReturn` isn't should be `success: loadReturn()` or `success:function(){   success: loadReturn(); }`?

Comment: also, you're using jquery but you prefer to use `innerHTML()` it's much easy to use `$("#defaultcode").html('text').fadeIn('slow')` in jquery..

Comment: @DrixsonOseña -- No, `loadReturn` is the correct way, if you use `loadReturn()` it will invoke the function immediately and throw an error.

Comment: @tymeJV can you put your `load.php`?

Comment: $errorcode = 0;

 $data = "<![CDATA[

 <h3>a title</h3>
 <p>blah blah</p>

 ]]>";

sendData($errorcode,$data);

function sendData($errorcode,$data)
{
 echo "
 <data>
  <errorcode>" . $errorcode . "</errorcode>
  <data>" . $data . "</data>
 </data>
 ";
}

Comment: Hmm, I think something else may be wrong. I've used this format for other pages with no problem. But I think it is actually printing it out when it is assigned, and then again when it is sent to the function.

Comment: FIXED! I think I was using a bad variable name. Wouldn't have figured it out without all the help though. Changed the variable name from data to imadork and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I try to fixed your code to the right ways. but I dont think code is wrong. it should be you have send  two `data` tag from `load.php`. please check your returned `data`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'load.php',
        success: loadReturn
    });

    function loadReturn(data) {

        // check your data
        console.log(data);

        // jQuery will parse for you automatically
        var $xml = $(data);

        var $errorcode = $xml.find('errorcode');
        var $data = $xml.find('data');

        // set html before fadeIn
        $("#defaultcode").html($data.text()).fadeIn(300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this $("#defaultcode").html($data.text()).fadeIn(300); I had no idea they could be combined in that way. :-)

Comment: You can do this because many of jQuery methods return it-self. It called `method chaining`